# Best way to make switch out 3d models at runtime in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

im building a city-builder game and i wanted to get your input on the best (performance wise) way to simulate a building being build. I have 5 .fbx models for different stages of the building progress (20%,40%,60%,80%,100% done). So my question is what is the best way to add these models in the game and change them out during the building progress.

should i add all models to an empty game object and just switch the activity on and off ? should i make prefabs for all models and switch them out on a gameobject? or should i do something completely different?

thanks!

Comment: opinion based and case specific but in general disabling and enabling is better then Instantiate and destroy from the performance perspective. On the other hand more objects (also inactive) means more memory required. You should maybe have one prefab for the building process but as soon as it is done switch it out with one prefab for already completed buildings.

Comment: If the building models are reused around the city, then you could have a pool of the models that you always grab from, and only expand the pool if more are needed. Also, IMO people mostly worry about the wrong things when it comes to performance in unity games. Instantiating a few simple models in one frame is no biggie, i would worry more about your draw calls, shadows, lighting and model import setting etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends from situation to situation.
Few cases:

- If you only have few object to switch, than you can just make some simple switcher and enable/disable them.

  - If you have 100+ objects and you don't know which one will be enabled at the beginning, but you know that it would be only one of them switched not all, than it's better just to instantiate them.
  - If you have 100+ objects and in runtime you can switch all of them(for example change model on every 20 seconds for 0..100), then probably the best solution is to create some Polling system (instantiate on loading and use it latter) and to reuse/switch them whenever you want.